# Pymssql (or similar) function to return all available stored procedures

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

Our database engineer builds stored procedures for us to call from Python/R etc. These now number in the multiple 10s, over 2-3 databases.

I've got records of what 70% of them do, but I wondered if there was a quick/dirty way to query the database(s), and pull back a list of available stored procedures (given the supplied logins within the connection string.)

I typically use

```
sql = "
EXEC stored_proc_name
@param1 = 'xyz',
@param2 = 'abc'
"
cnxn = pymssql.connect(
                host = r'ip.ad.dr.es.',
                port = '1433',
                user = r'db_user',
                password = r'pdws',
                database = 'db_name'
                    )
```

and then the wonderful pd.read_sql_query(sql, cnxn). This works fine - as long as i know the stored proc name and params required.

I've got most of them hard coded in to a module, but just thought i'd see if anyone knows of some in-built functionality to interrogate the database for this info - at least the available stored procedures, but also the required params too, if at all possible.

Comment: Just connect to the database with Management Studio, and check what you'll see in [sys.procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-procedures-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) view. You should see the parameters for example using `sp_help procedurename`

Comment: Yes I know I can do that, and I do that too - I’m wondering if there’s a python way/call to return that

Comment: You can of course run the exact same SQL in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this became quickly irrelevant for the initial issue, but just this week became relevant again.

What I was looking for was:

```
sql_SPs = """Select [NAME] from sysobjects where type = 'P' and category = 0"""
```

and when called as:

```
df_1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql_SPs, cnxn)
```

Returns a dataframe (fine in this instance) with the stored procedures listed